# Matching two elements not in the same node by XPATH

Tags: xpath

I need to match two elements that are not in the same node. Each xpath selector by itself is valid but I need to put them together. I have tried using an 'and' between them, but it does not work.

selectors that work individually:

```
//label[@class='NewLabel']

//span[contains(text(),'jimbo.smith')]
```

HTML:

```
<div> 
  <!----> 
    <label class="NewLabel">New</label>
    <span>jimbo.smith       </span>     
</div>
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//*[self::label[@class='NewLabel'] or self::span[contains(.,'jimbo.smith')]]
```

will select all `label` elements with a `class` attribute value of `NewLabel` and all `span` elements with a string value that contains the substring `jimbo.smith`.

Comment: I think it's important to point out here that counter-intuitively to some, while the OP wanted to place an "and" between the xpaths, the key was using "or"

Comment: @BillHileman: Yeah, in a colloquial sense, both `label` *and* `span` elements are needed, but logically that translates into an `or` between the joined tests.